# How would I add a "+1" animation when my node comes in contact with a coin?

Tags: xcode, swift

I already got the node to collect the coins but I want some type of animation when this happens. How would I add a "+1" animation every time the node collects a coin? I dont know if I should use a SKAction and have it run an action every time a contact occurs between the node and coins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i did it with a SKAction (when you put this code in the "update" method it will show everytime you earn a coin):

```
if CGRectIntersectsRect(player.frame, coin.frame) {
        coins++ //your variable

        let addCoinsLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ChalkboardSE-Regular")
        addCoinsLabel.text = "+1"
        addCoinsLabel.fontSize = 40
        addCoinsLabel.fontColor = UIColor.redColor()
        addCoinsLabel.zPosition = 200
        addCoinsLabel.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: self.frame.size.height*0.7)
        self.addChild(addCoinsLabel)

        let actionLabelfadeIn = SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.5)
        let actionLabelMove = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 100), duration: 0.5)
        let actionRemoveFromParent = SKAction.removeFromParent()

        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([actionLabelfadeIn, actionLabelMove, actionLabelFadeOut, actionRemoveFromParent])

        addCoinsLabel.runAction(sequence)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you it works. I have a question.......could I use a SKSpriteNode instead of A SKLabel. I would like to use my own image for this.

Comment: Would you know how to make a long press on the left and right side of the screen. So every time the user presses on the left side the node moves to the left and if there's a long press on the right side the node moves to the right. I have been trying for a while to get this to work and can't seem to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: This is another question which doesnt fit in here but you can apply a force or an impuls to your player erverytime the user touches the screen.

Comment: My bad. I was gonna make a new question but I wanted to ask you if you knew.